# Node.js http.get with Node.js step module

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js world, kind of stuck in situation.

below code is for reference:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var step = require('step');
    var request = require('request');

            exports.readimage2 = function(req, res){

        //res.send(200,'OK');

        //var image_url = 'http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/artikelen/39/k20d-image.jpg'; //--- 10mb
        //var image_url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Snake_River_(5mb).jpg'; 
        //var image_url = 'http://www.sandia.gov/images2005/f4_image1.jpg';  //--- 2mb
        var image_url = 'http://www.fas.org/nuke/guide/pakistan/pakistan.gif'; // --- some KB

        http.get(image_url,
                function(responseData) {
                    var data = new Buffer(parseInt(responseData.headers['content-length'],10));
                    var pos = 0;

                    responseData.on('data', function(chunk) {
                      chunk.copy(data, pos);
                      pos += chunk.length;
                    });

                    responseData.on('end', function () {
                        res.send(200, data);
                    }); 
                });

    };
```

Above code fails working for large files if i use it with step module.

Anyone suggest how to do it properly with step.

Comment: Do you use `step` anywhere besides requiring its module?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with step? If it's parallel image downloads you might find the async library works for this.

Comment: Amberlamps yes I have used step but that code is failing...
@SteveHaigh its not parallel downloading of image actual image downloading is somewhat 4 step function which causing other db & service calls to collapse as they depend on success of image being downloaded.

Comment: You should edit your question to post **the failing code**, so we can help you. It seems to be that you've posted the working code, and ask why "the other code" fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here how i did it using step..... although the request module did same for image buffer download thanks to a post on stackoverflow just need to set encoding to null in request to work for buffer response.

```
var canvas = new Canvas(3000, 3000),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        Image = Canvas.Image;

    var image_url = "http://www.a2hosting.com/images/uploads/landing_images/node.js-hosting.png";
    //var image_url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/AsterNovi-belgii-flower-1mb.jpg';


    step(

    function() {
        request.get({
            url: image_url,
            encoding: null
        }, this);
    },

    function(err, response, body) {

        var img = new Image;
        img.src = body;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        //res.send(200, data);
        res.send(200, '<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');

    }

    );
```

---

Below is the code working for simple http module of node.

```
var http = require('http');
 var step = require('step');
 var request = require('request');

 exports.imagedownload = function(req, res){
    step(
            function(){
                console.log('*********** image download start ***********');
                fndownload(this);
            },
            function(err, result){
                if(err) {

                }
                console.log('*********** image download end ***********');
                res.send(200, result);
            }
    ); 
 };

 function fndownload(callback) {

     var image_url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Snake_River_(5mb).jpg'; // --- some KB

     http.get(image_url,
             function(responseData) {
                 var data = new Buffer(parseInt(responseData.headers['content-length'],10));
                 var pos = 0;

                 responseData.on('data', function(chunk) {
                   chunk.copy(data, pos);
                   pos += chunk.length;
                 });

                 responseData.on('end', function () {
                     //res.send(200, data);
                     callback(null, data);
                 }); 
             });
 };
```

Comment: why r u passing "this" as second parameter to request.get? - what's the value for 'this' at this point? - it makes no sense to use "step" with only one function. - there should be more fns inside the step call. I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to help you.

Comment: note: you can edit your post, you don't need to post another answer.

Comment: Instead of using 'step', check my lib, Wait.For at   https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Comment: @LucioM.Tato this is passed for the callback to return the response of whatever the request.get get from the uri.

yeah step should be used for more than 1 async calls scenario....
but here i was required to wait till the responseData.on('end') of http.get finishes his work...

sure i will look forward to your lib... thanks.